# How to offset x and y axis grid points and labels using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want my line graph to look like this: 
https://ibb.co/F3c5QBt

This is my JS code:

```
let traffic=document.getElementById('web-traffic').getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(traffic, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['16-22', '23-29', '30-5', '6-12', '13-19', '20-26', '27-3','4-10','11-17','18-24','25-31'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(226,227,247, 0.6)',
            borderColor: 'purple',
            data: [600, 700, 650, 800, 900, 950, 1000, 850, 900, 550, 1000, 2000, 1500]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: {
                right: 300
            }
        },
        scales: {
            gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true
            },
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 500,
                    max: 2500,
                    stepSize: 500
                }
            }], 
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // labelOffset: 50
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

I tried setting the x and y-axis offset values but found it to be a sloppy solution. I then tried setting offsetGridLines to true, but that seemed to have no effect.

Does the number of data points and labels matter?

How do I achieve the desired look of the labels and grid lines in the photo above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chart has some data points on the grid lines and some between. You can't do that in Chart.js. Only one or the other which can be controlled using `offsetGridLines`